# Boost::graph equivalent for java?

Tags: java, boost

Is there any equivalent to boost::graph for java?
Or even an adaption of boost::graph (a wrapper?).

I tried JGraphIT but there seem to be compilation
errors on first sight.
Any alternative? Any standard library 
for advanced tree-structures?

Comment: I don't know boost:graph that well but a quick google search for `java graph library` returned [graphstream-project.org](http://graphstream-project.org/) for example. Btw, JGraphIT should be available in binary (jar) form, so where do you experience compilation errors?

Comment: Just tried to compile the JGraphAdapterDemo.java with the jGrapT*.lib added in the eclipse properties. The error-message is "Rectangle2D cannot be resolved to a type".

Comment: Well, that depends on which `Rectangle2D` is missing (there are at least two in JDK 8) but this sounds like a classpath problem - at least one JAR (not .lib) seems to be missing.

Comment: Which is now hosted on github: https://github.com/jrtom/jung

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have used Jung.  The latest version is 3.0 and is part of the google guava code.  Here is the current link: https://code.google.com/p/jung/wiki/Manual.